# Run automatically a python script with inputs after a raspberry reboot

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that i need to run continuously in my raspberry. The script reads an input, then generates a JSON and make a http petition. The code is some like this:

```
    import json
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime

    url = 'an ip'

    def main():

        while True:
            tagRFID = str(input("Tag: "))

            date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

            data = { 'tagRfid'    : tagRFID,
                     'datetime'   : date_time}

            try:
                solicitud = requests.post(url, json = data, timeout = 2)
                obj = json.loads(solicitud.text)

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                pass

    main()
```

For diferent reasons, the electrical network has constant power outages, and that causes a reboot in the raspberry. I have used crontab for execute the script after a reboot in this way:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && python3 /home/pi/pathToScript/script.py
```

This doesnt solve my problem, i think that the input() line doesnt function in the reboot.
Tnank you for your answers guys.

Comment: Would it be possible for a subprocess call to supply the input required?  Or would this be too dynamic and needs human user input?

Comment: The process needs the interaction with the user, is a user input.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply accomplish the usual procedure for running a script at boot on your raspberry. Right?

1. create a myscriptBoot.service in your /home/pi/
2. fill myscriptboot with this ... (using your correct python bin location in ExecStart)
   `[Unit]

   Description=My service
   After=network.target

   [Service]

   ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/pathToScript/script.py
   WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/pathToScript/
   inherit=StandardOutput
   StandardError=inherit
   Restart=always
   User=pi

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target`
3. Copy and set privileges
   `$cp /home/pi/myscriptBoot.service /etc/systemd/system/` 
   `$sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/myscriptBoot.service`
4. Enable service
   `$sudo systemctl enable myscriptBoot.service`
5. Start service
   `$sudo systemctl start myscriptBoot.service`
6. Reboot

NB For each change in myscriptBoot.service you need to ...
`$sudo systemctl daemon-reload`